# Istio: Envoy filter to remove server header

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

I would like to remove the server header being returned in the HTTP response when hitting the Health Check port 15021 for istio. Here is a example response:

```
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< date: Tue, 08 Aug 2023 20:22:56 GMT
< server: envoy
< content-length: 0
```

The current filter I have that removes server in the HTTP response for ports 80/443 is but not for 15021:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: remove-server-headers
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: NETWORK_FILTER
      match:
        listener:
          filterChain:
            filter:
              name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
      patch:
        operation: MERGE
        value:
          typed_config:
            "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
            server_header_transformation: PASS_THROUGH
    - applyTo: ROUTE_CONFIGURATION
      patch:
        operation: MERGE
        value:
          response_headers_to_remove:
            - "x-envoy-upstream-service-time"
            - "server"
```